# Daily sftp stops working, and weekly sshd fails and needs reinstall

Tags: centos, ssh, sftp

My server has daily issues with its `SFTP`. Everyday I need to change the `SFTP` subsystem.

Everyday it gets reset to:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

While it has to be:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

And now every week I get a new issue where ssh is not working at all. In order for me to get `ssh` working again, I reinstall `ssh-server` with `yum`. 
This needs to be done by adding a remote console to the server, and this is obviously very time consuming.

I have no clue whats going wrong.

Comment: Have you looked in the system logs?  Does this problem happen around the same time everyday?  What kind of automated (cron) scripts are you running?

Comment: First problem could be worked around by linking: `ln -s /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server /usr/libexec/sftp-server`, but I would reinstall sshd to solve both problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

THis still occured daily. but solved it by setting a cron reinstall yum install -y openssh-server
never had the issue anymore.

Comment: That's really not a "solution". You need to find the root cause of the problem (or rebuild your system to eliminate it) - throwing in a hack like this to work around virtually guarantees future problems...

Comment: I absolutely cannot imagine any system administrator would want to be responsible for a server on which there was a cron job reinstalling packages. I'm surely going to have nightmares after having heard about that approach.